# Xcode is making me use temporary variable...?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Newbie to Objective-C....

I have a real simple .h file:

```
@interface IdentityManager : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *username;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *password;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *connString;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *token;
@end
```

And I <del>want</del> need to grab text from some text fields in another object to load into an  Identity object:

```
self.identity.username = self.usernameTextField.text;
self.identity.password = self.passwordTextField.text;
```

Yep, it's a login page. Problem is that the username would not be set. After hours trying to find out why, I found that putting the value of *self.usernameTextField.text* into a local variable and passing the value of **that** to the Identity object worked:

```
NSString *tempUsername  = self.usernameTextField.text; 
self.identity.username = self.tempUsername;
self.identity.password = self.passwordTextField.text;
```

I have no idea why this would be. I can only guess that all my messing around has somehow left a trace of some old references in Xcode's cache somewhere.

More likely, I'm an idiot. Better, I'm still learning.

Should I be using NSMutableString?

I think something similar is happening again elsewhere. Use of a temp variable helping to achieve my goal.

Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: These two lines don't make sense: `NSString *tempUsername  = self.usernameTextField.text; 
self.identity.username = self.tempUsername;` shouldn't it be `tempUsername` instead of `self.tempUsername` ?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say your problem is probably that all the properties on your `IndentityManager` are weak and probably being de-alloc'ed immediately, maybe change them to strong and it'll probably fix your issues.

Comment: Yes, because he is using a property, which might have been initialized somewhere else?

Comment: Why on earth are you using weak reference in a manager?

Comment: Because I'm learning, thats why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really think your second solution actually fixes the issue. It's probably something else.

Though it's really wrong for a manager class to have a `weak` reference. In OOP, classes and especially managers should own the object they have as property.

So you should use `strong` references instead of `weak`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *username;
```

Additionally, you don't want any changes outside the class to modify the variable, so you should be passing a copy of the object:

```
NSString *username = self.usernameTextField.text;
self.identity.username = [username copy];
```

Alternatively, you can declare the property as `copy` instead of `strong` and you don't have to worry about copying the string every time you set it. (Credit to [albertamg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/375300/albertamg))

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *username;
```

Comment: Or declare the property as `copy` instead of `strong` and you don't have to worry about copying the string every time you set it.

Comment: Thanks albertamg. I thought of adding that, but wasn't sure how copy interacted with ARC. Edited my answer.